# element position in arraylist after sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, dictionary

Assuming i have the following :

```
List<Double> test = new ArrayList<Double>();
test.add(1.0);
test.add(1.3);
test.add(1.1);
test.add(1.2);
test.add(1.5);
```

If i want to sort the values, i can use `Collections.sort(test)`. Which will sort them in asc order. Is there a way to still keep a reference to the original position before the sort occured?

e.g. after the sort it would be

```
test.add(1.0);
test.add(1.1); - would be index position 3
test.add(1.2); - would be index position 2
test.add(1.3);
test.add(1.5);
```

Is this possible or just a wrong approach?

Comment: if you want to keep the original indexes, make a second List (duplicate) and sort that one, not the original one

Answer (score 2):

Since `Collections.sort()` sorts the original list and doesn't give you a copy, no. You'd have to take a copy of the list prior to sorting.

An alternative would be to create a list of *tuples* - the original value and its index, and sort using a comparator comparing on the value alone e.g.

```
test.add(new Pair(1, 1.0));
test.add(new Pair(2, 1.2));
Collections.sort(test, new PairComparator()); // this sorts on the 2nd value of each Pair
```

etc. That would give you a list of tuples with the original position index recorded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HashMap

```
Map<Integer, Double> test = new Hashmap<>();
test.put(1, 1.0);
test.put(2, 1.3); //etc.
```

Even if you sort it, keys won't change.

Comment: Since its a map, does it not require that all keys to be unique? Its very likely that I would have same double values in the array list

Comment: Your keys are the original positions, and hence would be unique. Your values could be duplicated however

Comment: How do you sort it by value then? is there a utility i can use?

Comment: Call the method values() on map (i.e. `test.values()`) and you will get the list of map values to manipulate with them. Key is just used to set unique identifier to an element.

For more info on Hashmaps, checkout http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_hashmap.htm seems good enough for understanding the topic

Comment: And for solution for sorting the Hashmap (and lots of other stuff), Google is your friend :D -> http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/